# Getting value of OptionID when clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I get the value of `OptionID` when clicking on the Add (`.plus-link`) link?

Each li may contain select (dropdown) or without it.

```
    <ul>

  <li>
    <div class="menux">
        <div class="text-block">
            <div class="text-holder">
                <h3>  Item Name </h3>
                <p> Description </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div optionid="46812" class="price"> <strong>£4.90</strong> </div>
        <div class="add-item">  <a class="plus-link" href="#">plus</a>  </div>
    </div>
</li>

<li>
    <div class="menux">
        <div class="text-block">
            <div class="text-holder">
                <h3> Item Name 2 </h3>                                                                                                      </h3>
                <p> Description  </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <form class="menu-form" action="#">
        <fieldset>
            <a class="plus-link" href="#">plus</a>
            <select id="optionid" class="select">
                <option value="1">9", £3.99</option>
                <option value="2">12", £5.49</option>
            </select>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</li>

</ul>
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li .plus-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert( $(this).attr("OptionID") );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to grab the .siblings('.OptionID'). Then assuming you just want the value of that combo box, you would use .val() to get the selected value:

http://jsfiddle.net/MacAnthony/zzrrp/

**EDIT**

In response to the edit try this. It will look for both the select and the div with the attribute and should be able to traverse trees where it isn't a direct siblings.

http://jsfiddle.net/MacAnthony/zzrrp/4/

Comment: You switched the selector on me. I didn't notice you changed it from a class to an id. That took me a bit to realize. The edit should work.

Comment: Thank you for edit. It is work now :) The code seem a bit long.. Must be an easy way? How would you place class or id in the select and without select? Just make the JS code shorter? Thanks

Comment: You need either need an "if" or a ternary (like I did) since the value will be retrieved in 2 different ways. It could be shortened up by consolidating some of the code, but really 6 lines doesn't seem that bad. The best way to shorten this code would be to make another function that would do the ternary for you and just call that function. I don't know how much of this code you could go without. http://jsfiddle.net/MacAnthony/zzrrp/5/

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

---

Edit slightly misunderstood question there and updated for new markup

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("li .plus-link").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var prev = $(this).closest('li').find('#optionid, .price');
    var OptionId = prev.val() || prev.attr('optionid');
    console.log(OptionId);
});
});
```

Example at http://jsfiddle.net/nickywaites/pTPr8/1/

Comment: Ok I've updated it a little bit although it is similar to MacAnthony's response.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to get the attribute OptionID using `$(this)` which refers to the anchor.You should use `prev()` to traverse the tree and get the selectbox value.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li .plus-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert( $(this).prev(".OptionID").val() );
    });
});
```

In this case. You should use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("li .plus-link").click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        alert( $(this).siblings('.OptionID').val() );
    });
});
```

Comment: I believe that should be a `.OptionID`

Comment: I don't think this gets the value of the div if that is what is required.

Comment: @user622378 can you be specific what exactly you want. Because there are two anchors.